# How to fold a Scala iterator and get a lazily evaluated sequence as result?

Tags: scala

I have an iterator of strings, where each string can be either `"H"` (header) or `"D"` (detail). 
I want to split this iterator into blocks, where each block starts with one header and can have 0 to many detail.

I know how to solve this problem loading everything into memory. For example, the code bellow:

```scala
Seq("H","D","D","D","H","D","H","H","D","D","H","D").toIterator
  .foldLeft(List[List[String]]())((acc, x) => x match {
    case "H" => List(x) :: acc
    case "D" => (x :: acc.head) :: acc.tail })
  .map(_.reverse)
  .reverse
```

returns 5 blocks - `List(List(H, D, D, D), List(H, D), List(H), List(H, D, D), List(H, D))` - which is what I want.

However, instead of `List[List[String]]` in the result, I want either `Iterator[List[String]]` or some other structure that allows me to evaluate the result lazily and *do not load the entire input into memory if the entire iterator in consumed*, I want to load into memory only the block being consumed at a time (e.g.: when I call `iterator.next`).

How can I modify the code above to achieve the result I want?

EDIT: I need this in Scala 2.11 specifically, as the environment I use sticks to it. Glad to also accept answers for other versions though.

Comment: I have trouble understanding this part: *and do not load the entire list into memory if the entire iterator in consumed*. Doesn't this mean the program has *examined* all elements already? If the result of the algorithm is not stored in some way (in memory or on disk), then there seems to be no way to retrieve it except iterating over the list again.

Comment: What I meant with this is I expect to have an iterator as a return or something that behaves like it. A stream, for instance, according to what I was told (I might be wrong) will keep in memory all elements already consumed, isn't it? I don't want to consume twice, but I want to consume blocks.

Comment: I am just not sure it would be more idiomatic to use an iterator, a stream or a view, that's why I didn't want to stick to an iterator as result. But the requirement is - the input iterator could be potentially infinite (like a fibonacci sequence), but I want to keep in memory just the elements I process. e.g. : I will read a block, save to file, free memory, read the next block.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify more, hope it's clear now, otherwise just let me know.

Comment: Is my answer works for you?

Comment: I've added proposition without sliding. It is bit longer and has additional type limitation but could be more efficient, not sure yet. Have nice day :)

Comment: Thanks! Your answers really helped me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the simplest implementation I could find (It's generic and lazy):

```scala
/** takes 'it' and groups consecutive elements 
 *  until next item that satisfy 'startGroup' predicate occures. 
 *  It returns Iterator[List[T]] and is lazy 
 *  (keeps in memory only last group, not whole 'it'). 
*/
def groupUsing[T](it:Iterator[T])(startGroup:T => Boolean):Iterator[List[T]] = {
  val sc = it.scanLeft(List.empty[T]) {
    (a,b) => if (startGroup(b)) b::Nil else b::a
  }

  (sc ++ Iterator(Nil)).sliding(2,1).collect { 
    case Seq(a,b) if a.length >= b.length => a.reverse
  }
}
```

use it like that:

```scala
val exampleIt = Seq("H1","D1","D2","D3","H2","D4","H3","H4","D5","D6","H5","D7").toIterator
groupUsing(exampleIt)(_.startsWith("H"))
// H1 D1 D2 D3 / H2 D4 / H3 / H4 D5 D6 / H5 D7
```

here is specyfication:

```
X | GIVEN            | EXPECTED     |
O |                  |              | empty iterator
O | H                | H            | single header
O | D                | D            | single item (not header)
O | HD               | HD           |
O | HH               | H,H          | only headers
O | HHD              | H,HD         |
O | HDDDHD           | HDDD,HD      |
O | DDH              | DD,H         | heading D's have no Header as you can see.
O | HDDDHDHDD        | HDDD,HD,HDD  |
```

scalafiddle with tests and additional comments:
https://scalafiddle.io/sf/q8xbQ9N/11

(if answer is helpful up-vote please. I spent a little too much time on it :))

**SECOND IMPLEMENTATION:**

You have propose version **that does not use** `sliding`. Here it is, but it has its own problems listed below.

```scala
def groupUsing2[T >: Null](it:Iterator[T])(startGroup:T => Boolean):Iterator[List[T]] = {
  type TT = (List[T], List[T])
  val empty:TT = (Nil, Nil)
  //We need this ugly `++ Iterator(null)` to close last group.
  val sc = (it ++ Iterator(null)).scanLeft(empty) {
    (a,b) => if (b == null || startGroup(b)) (b::Nil, a._1) else (b::a._1, Nil)
  }

  sc.collect { 
    case (_, a) if a.nonEmpty => a.reverse
  }
}
```

Traits:

- (-) It works only for `T>:Null` types. We just need to add element that will close last collection on the end (null is perfect but it limits our type).
- (~) it should create same amount of trsh as previous version. We just create tuples in first step instead of second one.
- (+) it does not check length of List (and this is big gain to be honest).
- (+) In core it is Ivan Kurchenko answer but without extra boxing.

Here is scalafiddle: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/q8xbQ9N/11

Comment: Dude... That's beautiful ... I was surprise how something so easy to do in imperative programming could be so hard to me in functional paradigm. But looking at the answer now, it seems obvious and so easy to understand. 
The sliding part was tricky - you check whether the length changed, which is something specific for this use case... But maybe you could have checked for "startGroup" again there, right? If b.head is the start of a group, you can collect...

Comment: Thinking back now, do you really need the sliding above? I think the best answer would be a combination of yours and Ivan's one above... You could collect directly from `scanLeft` and call startGroup just once, without checking the length. It's impressive how I wasn't able to solve it before and thanks to your answer now I can even see possible optimizations. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Scala 2.13.x then you might create a new `Iterator` by unfolding over the original `Iterator`.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val data = Seq("H","D","D","D","H","D","H","H","D","D","H","D").iterator

val rslt = Iterator.unfold(data.buffered){itr =>
  Option.when(itr.hasNext) {
    val lb = ListBuffer(itr.next())
    while (itr.hasNext && itr.head == "D")
      lb += itr.next()
    (lb.toList, itr)
  }
}
```

testing:

```
rslt.next()   //res0: List[String] = List(H, D, D, D)
rslt.next()   //res1: List[String] = List(H, D)
rslt.next()   //res2: List[String] = List(H)
rslt.next()   //res3: List[String] = List(H, D, D)
rslt.next()   //res4: List[String] = List(H, D)
rslt.hasNext  //res5: Boolean = false
```

Comment: ufff, I forgot to mention I have to stick to scala 2.11 due to EMR restrictions... I will edit the question, but upvote the answer, thanks...

Comment: Also, nit: you used itr.head - so it's a buffered iterator, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

I think `scanLeft` operation might help in this case, if you would like use Scala 2.11 version.

I would like to come up with next solution, but I'm afraid it look more complicated then the original one:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    sealed trait SequenceItem
    case class SequenceSymbol(value: String) extends SequenceItem
    case object Termination extends SequenceItem

    /**
      * _1 - HD sequence in progress
      * _2 - HD sequences which is ready
      */
    type ScanResult = (List[String], List[String])
    val init: ScanResult = Nil -> Nil

    val originalIterator: Iterator[SequenceItem] = Seq("H","D","D","D", "H","D", "H", "H","D","D", "H","D")
      .toIterator.map(SequenceSymbol)

    val iteratorWithTermination: Iterator[SequenceItem] = originalIterator ++ Seq(Termination).toIterator
    val result: Iterator[List[String]] = iteratorWithTermination
      .scanLeft(init) {
        case ((progress, _), SequenceSymbol("H")) =>  List("H") -> progress
        case ((progress, _), SequenceSymbol("D")) => ("D" :: progress) -> Nil
        case ((progress, _), Termination) => Nil -> progress
      }
      .collect {
        case (_, ready) if ready.nonEmpty => ready
      }
      .map(_.reverse)

    println(result.mkString(", "))
  }
```

Types added for example readability.
Hope this help!

Comment: This answer was probably more didactic and I would be happy to accept it as well. However, as Scalway answer got more votes, I will accept it as best, but I am really thankful for this answer as well, it was very useful and I upvoted it!

Comment: @mvallebr Sure, you are free to choose, what ever you like to, and I agree that solution looks better. I appreciate your attention and upvote!